# Trying upgrade phongap android app to Cordova 3.5.1 in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-cli

[This is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCVTY.jpg)

[Here is another](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O37Na.jpg)

I'm trying to upgrade an app in Eclipse. This is what I did at command line:

```
npm install -g cordova
cordova create myapp com.myapp.myapp
cd myapp
cordova platform add android
cordova build android
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device    
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.network-information    
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.battery-status    
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device-motion    
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device-orientation    
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.geolocation    
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera    
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.media-capture    
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.media    
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file    
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file-transfer    
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs    
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.vibration    
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.contacts    
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.globalization    
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.splashscreen    
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser    
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.console
```

I imported this project to eclipse, but the src folder shows errors in all files. I tried in `Resource > Resource Filters` to exclude all files and to clean the project, but all the errors came back again. Please help to resolve this error. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post your errors?

Comment: uploaded two screenshots. Please take a look.

Comment: What do the errors say?

Comment: The screen shots explains them I believe. Please click the links above. 'This is what I get' & 'Here is another'.

Comment: try with android studio

Comment: Thanks jcesamobile. In Android Studio it worked flawlessly without any error. My previous apk compiled with cordova 2.9 has been rejected by Google Play Store and  now finding it almost impossible to remove it. How do I resubmit this new apk ? Please help.